Application of Rouchés Theorem
I struggle with the following statement:
Let $f (z)$ be a holomorphic function
inside the unit disk $|z| < 1$, with the Taylor series expansion:
$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nz^n$. Assume $f(z)$ is continous on the closed unit disk and has counted with multiplicity exaclty $k$ zeros inside the open unit disk.
I want to show, that $\min_{|z|=1}|f(x)|\leq |c_0|+...+|c_k|$.
I tried arguing by contraposition but then got stuck. Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2808368/42969

Suppose $|f(z)|>|c_0|+\ldots+|c_k|$ for all $z$ on the boundary. Let $g(z)=c_0+c_1z+\ldots+c_kz^k$. Note that $|g(z)|\leq|c_0|+|c_1||z|+\ldots+|c_k||z|^k=|c_0|+\ldots+|c_k|<|f(z)|$ for all $z$ on the boundary. But then Rouché's theorem implies that $f$ and $f-g$ has the same number of zeroes in the unit disk. In other words $f-g$ has exactly $k$ zeroes in the unit disk.
Further note that $f(z)-g(z)=c_{k+1}z^{k+1}+c_{k+2}z^{k+2}+\ldots=z^{k+1}h(z)$ which has at least $k+1$ zeroes counting multiplicity in the unit disk.
